# ColdFusion RESTFUL API POST not working in CF 2016 Server

Tags: json, rest, api, coldfusion

Just upgraded our web server software to Windows 2012 r2, ColdFusion 2016, and MSSQL 2016 database. One of those upgrades seems to have broken my REST API.

The old server (Windows 2008 r2, CF 10, MSSQL 2008) is still running and this test page shows the same exact POST call on the new server (fail) and the old server (success).

https://www.govrs.com/restapi/test.cfm

Nothing found in the CF error logs at all.

The error message (JSON) I am getting back from the NEW server is...

***{"Message":"The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}***

The interesting thing is - that is not one of my pre-defined error messages, so I think it's being generated automatically from ColdFusion - and it's formatted as JSON.

I have tried adding one of the following header(s) at a time, with no luck.

```
<cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Content-Type" value="multipart/form-data">
or
<cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

(POST) File upload works fine with no header on the CF10 server.

Do you have any ideas that could lead me in the right direction to fix the error?

Here is the code snippet that is failing (CF 2016 server).

```
<cfhttp url="https://www.govrs.com/rest/api/uploadplanogram/3458825" result="resu" method="post">
    <cfhttpparam name="file" file="D:\Websites\2020\images\demo.pdf" type="file">
</cfhttp>
```

Here is the code snippet that is working (CF 10 server).

```
<cfhttp url="https://demo1.govrs.com/rest/api/uploadplanogram/3458825" result="resu" method="post">
    <cfhttpparam name="file" file="D:\Websites\2020\images\demo.pdf" type="file">
</cfhttp>
```